# Triangle and parallel lines

Tags: triangles

[image]

L1 and l2 are parallel how can I find the angle of x , y , z ?

Comment: I think all you can say is that $x+y+z=180^\circ$

Comment: @angryavian, will you explain ?

Comment: @KF2 Hint: extend $L_2$, which creates another angle $a$. You get a concave $7$-sided polygon with angles summing up to $(7-2)\cdot 180^{\circ}$ degrees. You get $x+y+z=180^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the angles are concerned, the angles are the same as though the figure were drawn with L2 lower so that it is the same as L1 and the figure were a closed figure.  The closed figure would have 7 sides so the sum of it's angles would be 180*(7 - 2) = 900.  The seven angles are 2 that are $a$.  $x$, $y$, $x$.  And 2 that are $360 -a$.  These add up to $x + y + x + 720 = 900$ so $x + y + z = 180$.  No more can be determined.